# ConTeXt imposition repeat each page

Tags: context, imposition

I'm converting my church's weekly handout to Context. The format is half an 8.5x11 page, printed on the front and back.

What I need is the equivalent of the ConTeXt imposition 2SIDE schema, except with the half pages repeated once, so that...

```
Printed Page 1 === Half Page 1, Half Page 1
Printed Page 2 === Half Page 2, Half Page 2
```

I know I could probably compile the first file and then rearrange the resulting PDF with imposition, but that seems unwieldily. I'd much rather do it in one Context file if at all possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hans emailed me.  There is a high-level interface for repeating pages and it is far easier to use than I thought.  It gets difficult only when your desired number of repetitions is incommensurate with the page dimensions.

```
\setuppapersize[A5][A4,landscape]
\setuplayout[nx=2]

\starttext
    \dorecurse{10}{\input knuth\relax}
\stoptext
```

[image]

#### Old solution for reference

It's not so easy, as there is no high-level interface for this (there was a [thread on the mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2011/061582.html) long time ago).  You have to dig into the shipout routine to make this work.  The first thing you have to do is duplicate the page shipout.  This is done in `\page_boxes_shipout` in these two lines:

```
\finalizeshipoutbox\shipoutscratchbox
\page_shipouts_handle{\box\shipoutscratchbox}%
```

However, this is not enough because the shipout box is cleared after shipping out the page.  This is done in the page handler.  If you use the arranging method the handler is `\page_shipouts_arrange`.  The problem lies in these lines

```
\setbox\scratchbox\hpack
     {\page_otr_flush_every_stuff
      \page_otr_flush_special_content
      \box\shipoutscratchbox}%
```

The command `\box\shipoutscratchbox` clear the box after typesetting, so replace it with `\copy\shipoutscratchbox`.

Here is a full example:

```
\setuppapersize[A5][A4,landscape]
\setuparranging[2SIDE]

\unprotect

%
% from page_imp.mkiv
%

\def\page_boxes_shipout#1% or: \page_shipouts_apply
  {\dontcomplain         % redundant
   \ifcase\c_page_boxes_flush_n\else
     \page_boxes_flush_before
   \fi
   \the\everybeforeshipout
   \ifcase\shipoutfinalizemethod
     \page_shipouts_handle{#1}%
   \else
     \setbox\shipoutscratchbox\hpack{#1}% just in case there are objects there, hook for testing (will go away)
     \finalizeshipoutbox\shipoutscratchbox
     \page_shipouts_handle{\box\shipoutscratchbox}%
     % Duplicate the shipout
     \finalizeshipoutbox\shipoutscratchbox
     \page_shipouts_handle{\box\shipoutscratchbox}%
   \fi
   \setnextrealpageno       % so this comes before \everyaftershipout so in fact:
   \the\everyaftershipout   % at this point we're already on the next realpage
   \ifcase\c_page_boxes_flush_n\else
     \page_boxes_flush_after
   \fi}

\def\page_shipouts_arrange#1%
  {% \global\advance\shippedoutpages\plusone
   \begingroup
   \setbox\scratchbox\hpack
     {\page_otr_flush_every_stuff
      \page_otr_flush_special_content
      \copy\shipoutscratchbox}% \copy instead of \box
   \pusharrangedpage\scratchbox
   \deadcycles\zerocount
   \endgroup}

\protect

\starttext

\dorecurse{10}{\input knuth\relax}

\stoptext
```

First page of output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough response, @Henri! I would have never been able to come up with that one on my own!

Yet another reason I use ConTeXt as much as possible – such quick responses from those in the community. Much obliged!

Comment: @derBingle My original solution was *way* too complicated.  Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

ConTeXt provides a hook for the output routine which lets you manipulate the finished page. You can use this to place the content of each page twice on your paper.

```
\installshipoutmethod{REPEAT}
  {\dowithnextbox
     {\setbox\scratchbox\hpack to \paperwidth{\box\nextbox\hss}%
      \setbox\scratchbox\hpack               {\copy\scratchbox\box\scratchbox}%
      \invokepagehandler{normal}{\box\scratchbox}}
   \hpack}

\setuppapersize[A5][A4,landscape]

\setuppaper[method=REPEAT]

\starttext

\chapter{Knuth}

\input knuth

\chapter{Zapf}

\input zapf

\stoptext
```

[image: Repeat page output on paper]